# I can't connect to MariaDB from PHP7.4 and localhost

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a problem with the application. I have DirectAdmin and MariaDB installed, the problem is that I have several versions of PHP. From PHP 8.0-8.2 I can connect to MariaDB via localhost and 127.0.0.1, while from PHP7.4 I can only connect via IP address. When I want to connect via localhost, I get an error

```
(HY000/2002): No such file or directory in 
Connect failed: No such file or directory
```

But when I use 127.0.0.1 everything is fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does it connect to a specific database which exists?

Comment: @NigelRen I noticed a strange thing that when I add localhost:3306 instead of localhost, everything works. Only I have 200 domains and it's stupid to change it manually

Answer (score 0):

Check check your php.ini file and verify that `mysqli.default_socket` / `pdo_mysql.default_socket` points to the valid MariaDB socket file. You can check the socket file with `select @@socket`

When you connect via 127.0.0.1, you will be connecting through TCP/IP.